# TWINKLE SIP softphone : How to end a call from CLI

Tags: sip, voip, ubuntu-10.04

I have a bunch of portable touch screen PCs with Ubuntu (Lucid) and I want to have VOIP calls to my central IP Phone. I am using Twinkle SIP softphone and it works perfectly. I made a small GUI application with a button and pressing that button call is getting initiated to the IP phone. [twinkle has command line ability so I used: **twinkle --immediate --call**  with my GUI button.]

Now my problem is I want to have another button to disconnect the call also. The Twinkle manual shows a **bye** option in the command line mode, but it is not working. Any ideas ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create easy bash script

```
twinkle --cmd bye
```

Comment: wow, what a small and easy solution. thanx. it had been a long time after i posted the question and i had stopped the project as well. but ran it after all these years, and it worked.